# Opening ChromeDriver in fullscreen, selenium and python

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm attempting to open my ChromeDriver in full screen. 
I've tried everything possible and can't seem to find a solution for it. 
After searching throughout google and stackoverflow it seems many people have had the same issue, this is for mac os x.  I thought that doing the (command, shift, f) would work but it doesn't. Does anyone have a solution?

```
     from selenium import webdriver
     from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
     import time
     urls = [x,y,z]
     driver = webdriver.Chrome() #Would like chrome to start in fullscreen
     driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SHIFT, 'f') #not sure why this doesn't work.
     driver.get("https://example.com")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch chrome with argument "--kiosk" using chrome_options.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeOptions = Options()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--kiosk")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions) #Would like chrome to start in fullscreen
driver.get("https://example.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! @ssudungunta. I had seen this one, but did not know I had to import Options.

Answer (score 3):

A bit old question, but anyways - now we have **maximize_window** and **minimize_window** methods:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.minimize_window()
```