# How can I remove menu bar from google chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]How can I remove Google chrome menu bar when I launch automation login to prevent user click ellipsis or menu bar?

Comment: where do you see a menu bar exactly? when using firefox its auto turned off and in chrome i cant even find it, can you show a picture or something?

Comment: Hi Timeler, how can I disable new tab & on top right there is menu bar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening ChromeDriver in fullscreen, selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811752/opening-chromedriver-in-fullscreen-selenium-and-python)

Comment: Well i doubt you can disable that menu bar, and what do you mean by new tab? like that small plus button next to a tab?

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233162/how-to-disable-tabbed-browsing-toolbar-and-address-bar-in-selenium-webdriver , is in Java but it's same idea.